# Best way to use Java8 streams to implement this collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

```
private enum EnumVals {
        FIRST(new String[]{"a","b"}),
        SECOND(new String[]{"a","b","c","d"}),
          THIRD(new String[]{"d","e"});

        private String[] vals;

        EnumVals(String[] q) {
            vals=q;
        }

        public String[] getValues(){
            return vals;
        }
    };
```

What I need is the unique combined list of all EnumVals.getValues().

```
String[] allVals = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

I did something like below, but it throws error :

```
Stream.of(EnumVals.values()).map(w->w.getValues()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Mind the existence of *varargs*. They can greatly simplify code like the one in your question…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten the arrays.  Additionally, you can use [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) on the stream instead of collecting into a `HashSet`.

```
Arrays.stream(EnumVals.values())
    .map(EnumVals::getValues)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .distinct()
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```